# XQE-DS-0006 Unable to logon to the data source for user "audit" in oracle

Tags: oracle11g, cognos-10

For enabling audits in Cognos 10, a database has to be created with name Audit. While Audit is a system key word. After going through internet i created "Audit" user, that worked. While creating a connection to this audit schema, i am getting the following error;

**XQE-DS-0006 Unable to logon to the data source.**

This user is created in Oracle Database 11g Express Edition.

Comment: Can you connect to other databases on the same server, like your reporting source DB? When you setup the data source connection in Cognos Administration, use the Test button and try to pull a more meaningful error message.

Comment: I can connect to other databases on the same local server. This error message is one from the Test Screen itself.